# which URL will take search engine for SEO

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm confusing which URL will a search engine see.

In my product search page, the product URL will be "mysite.com/detail.php?pid=123&cat=main&subcat=sub"

when we click this it will redirect to "mysite.com/detail/123/main/sub". ( using .htaccess to redirect like this)

which URL will take search engine for SEO? if search engine wants to take this URL 'mysite.com/detail/123/main/sub' what should I do?

Comment: If you want the URL to be `/detail/123/main/sub`, then that is what you should output inside your HTML to begin with.

Comment: I think Google can handle this scenario and your SEO score will not suffer from this solution. Even though I suggest to solve url aliases in application router's logic rather than in web server configuration.

Comment: do you mean this is what your hypertext has? `<a href="mysite.com/detail/123/main/sub">mysite.com/detail.php?pid=123&cat=main&subcat=sub</a>`
or do you have `mysite.com/detail.php?pid=123&cat=main&subcat=sub` in `href` and the .htaccess redirects to beautified url?
If your .htaccess is redirecting to beautified url, why now have it in the `href`?

Comment: I couldn't change all of those places since it will affect other functionalities. so I changed the URL like 'mysite.com/detail.php?pid=123&cat=main&subcat=sub' and then redirect it to 'mysite.com/detail/123/main/sub'. may I know in this scenario which URL will search engine look?

Comment: thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google will take (to use in SERP) second one (real URL on final page) not just pointing version of URL.

But your pages can be seen on SERP later and on lower positions (page with no no-redirected pointers for them).

You should make all links use final URL version.